# Django rest framework and south migrations inside my repo - how to set it up correctly?

Tags: django, git, django-rest-framework, django-south

I'm using `Django==1.6.5` and `djangorestframework==3.0.3` with `South==0.8.4`. And I am using virtualenv.

In settings INSTALLED_APPS I have both `rest_framework.authtoken` and `rest_framework`. Isn't the `rest_framework.authtoken` redundant?

When I run migrations it creates the migrations in my `/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/my_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/authtoken/migrations`, which is of course not in my project's repo.

QUESTION:

How can I set up django rest framework to produce the migrations inside my project directory, so that, after running `schemamigration` locally, the only thing I have to run on server is `migrate`?

Answer (score 2):

You are using django 1.6.5, in this version migrations were not introduced so its may give you error on running migrations because django rest framework auth token migration tries to import migrations from django.db

Upgrade your south package from 0.8.4 to 1.0.1 version that will solve your problem Please check the following link related to south version 1.0.1
http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes/1.0.html

Comment: I upgraded to south 1.0.2. So how could I create the migration (which would generate the tokens for the users) into my app now?

Comment: To answer my question: a a result of running migrate manage.py task, authtoken's initial migration was run also, so I got the empty table. Then I wrote a data migration using the directions of the documentation.